# Why my python tkinter Button is not accessed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to do my computer science project with tkinter, it is a dice game, I have 3 UI window, the button on second one, when you click it, it will help you run function:"conti" but my VisualStudio said my button is not accessed.
This is my code

```
def GameWind():
    GW = tkinter.Tk()
    GW.geometry("1000x1000")
    GW.resizable(0,0)
    GW.title("In Game")
    GW.mainloop()
#Introduce window
def Introduce():
    Intro = tkinter.Tk()
    Intro.geometry("700x300")
    Intro.resizable(0,0)
    Intro.title("Introduce")
    ttk.Label(Intro,text ="...").pack()
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = "Sources Images\RULES.gif",master=Intro)
    ttk.Label(Intro,image = photo).pack() 
    def conti():
            GameWind
            Intro.quit
    GameB=tk.Button(Intro,text="Continue",command=conti,master=Intro).pack()
    Intro.mainloop()
```

But when I run it:

[image]

I try to search online for multiple hours, I found nothing.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You're not doing anything with value of `GameB`, that's why VS is showing a warning about unused variable. Also, `.pack()` returns None. It doesn't make sense to assign it to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As matswecja already mentioned in her comment you are not using GameB variable. Also `.pack()` method returns None. To Resolve the issue just remove the `GameB=`

Comment: You are welcome, you can mark the answer as correct so in the future people can see that this resolved the issue.

Comment: But how can I modify the location of it when I remove the GameB=, I think the (), I type height =, it is a error, thanks

Comment: Try this:
"myButton = tk.Button(root)" and the next line:
"myButton.pack()"

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many namespace. Why not try two namespaces.

- In line 23, `TypeError: Button.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'master'` Remove `master=Intro`.

Snippet re-wrote script:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


def GameWind():
    GW = tkinter.Tk()
    GW.geometry("1000x1000")
    GW.resizable(0,0)
    GW.title("In Game")
    GW.mainloop()
#Introduce window
def Introduce():
    Intro = tkinter.Tk()
    Intro.geometry("700x300")
    Intro.resizable(0,0)
    Intro.title("Introduce")
    ttk.Label(Intro,text ="...").pack()
    photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "p1.png",master=Intro)
    ttk.Label(Intro,image = photo).pack() 
    def conti():
            GameWind
            Intro.quit
    GameB = tkinter.Button(Intro,text="Continue",command=conti)
    GameB.pack()
    Intro.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Introduce()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Btw, it should work on gif. I didn't add gif